# How to get status from this response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, httpwebrequest

Im trying to write simple test to some gem: https://github.com/regedarek/soup-client

I have this response when I run in the console:

```
    ruby-1.9.2-p290 :022 > c.login
    I, [2012-02-15T23:12:09.681772 #12908] INFO -- : post https://www.soup.io/login
    D, [2012-02-15T23:12:09.681854 #12908] DEBUG -- request: Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    I, [2012-02-15T23:12:10.157908 #12908] INFO -- Status: 302
    D, [2012-02-15T23:12:10.158054 #12908] DEBUG -- response: server: "nginx/0.7.67"
    date: "Wed, 15 Feb 2012 22:12:11 GMT"
    content-type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    connection: "close"
    ...
    content-length: "94"
    status: "302"
    ...
    location: "http://soup-client.soup.io/?sessid=995f610405f8afe029b9038da6c22132"
    content-length: "0"
    status: "302"
    ...
    set-cookie: "soup_session_id=995f610405f8afe029b9038da6c22132; path=/; expires=Sun, 15 Feb 2032 22:12:13 GMT; HttpOnly"
    status: "200"
    content-length: "16024"
```

I would like to test this but how do I get the status from this response?

I already tried `c.login["status"].should == 200` but it's not working:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :025 >   c.login["status"]

...

status: "200"
vary: "Accept-Encoding"
content-length: "15700"
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):25
    from /home/rege/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

This is output of `c.login.inspect` -> https://gist.github.com/1842529

Comment: What does `c.login["status"]` show in the console?

Comment: ```NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass```

Comment: What type of object is `c` (`c.class` or `p c`) and how is its `#login` method defined`?

Comment: Object ```c``` is class ```Soup::Client``` and ```login``` method is [here](https://github.com/regedarek/soup-client/blob/tests/lib/soup-client/client.rb)

Comment: Please add the output from `puts c.login.inspect` to your question?

Comment: Added. https://gist.github.com/1842529

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged rspec, I'm going to give you the rspec answer:

```
get '/login'
last_response.status.should == 200
```

Comment: I think because this is only gem i cant use ```get``` so i receive ```undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0xa95a6dc>
```